# Roadmap for Apache Mesos on Windows

Tags: mesos

I see that there is now an effort to make Mesos available on Windows (servers at least).

https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/08/20/mesos-everywhere-apache-mesos-for-windows-server/

Does anyone know of updates/roadmap on this effort? I tried looking in https://github.com/apache/mesos/search?q=&type=Issues but don't see any issues for Windows support.

Comment: Just so you know, in the future, you are much more likely to get good answers to questions like these from the dev@apache.mesos.org list. Here, you'll take your chances that someone will know about the roadmap of a Mesos feature.

Comment: Also, the GitHub is a _mirror_ of the official repository, so this issues you find on that GitHub are not "real" tracked issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesos uses [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS) to track issues, that's why nothing shows up in GitHub. The Windows port is now [very actively being worked on](https://github.com/apache/mesos/commits?author=hausdorff). There are two JIRA epics that track the effort:

[Introduce CMake as an alternative build system.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-898)

[Mesos on Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3094)

The plan is to first port the Mesos Agent. Once it's done, it will become possible to have a cluster with Master(s) running on Linux and Agents running on either Linux or Windows (or both).

The current implementation of CMake-based build system is pretty functional. It allows to rope in all the dependencies for building the Agent as well as produces the Agent binary. The work on porting Mesos build system tooling (post-reviews script, bootstrap script, etc.) is currently under way.

Comment: Worth noting, of course, that those tickets are pretty comprehensive. The list of things we need to do to release beta a quite a bit shorter. Mostly a bunch of mechanical translation of APIs and a handful of MSVC compiler bugs to work through. (EDIT: this is alex, btw. :) )

Comment: Very useful, I will be sure to check out the mailing lists and JIRA. If I might leave a comment here as well, I would vote to have the masters also run on Windows. There are many IT shops where everything runs on Windows and as an ISV, to have to require them to run a Linux machine will be hard.

Comment: @Raylite3, if you want master support you should tell the dev@ list. It will help us prioritize correctly. If you don't tell the dev@ list, then there is no way the community has of knowing where the demand is.

Answer (score 2):

You could check out this thread http://search-hadoop.com/m/0Vlr6bGrJMIwE1j Alex reply his plan in this thread.